# Getting dialogflow error "conv.parameters.date.split is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm writing a function in the dialogflow inline editor that makes changes to a google calendar I've linked, and I keep getting the error:

```
  "error": "conv.parameters.date.split is not a function"
```

When I look in the logs on firebase or the fulfillment reposonse. I swear the function was just working the other day, but no matter what I seem to do, it doesn't work.

Here's the function:

```
app.intent('Make Appointment', (conv) => {
   const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(conv.parameters.date.split('T') [0] + 'T' + conv.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
   const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
   const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
  'en-US',
  { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
);

// Check the availibility of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
  return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
         conv.add(`Ok, your reservation for. ${appointmentTimeString} is booked`);
}).catch(() => {
      conv.add(`I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.`);
    });
});
```

I understand what the error is, I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to do this same thing using a different way that works for "conv".

Thanks!

**Note:** All my credentials in the code are correct for the google calendar api.

Comment: What version of node are you using on firebase cloud functions? Are you sure `date` is a string?

Comment: Using node 6, I’ll take a look that could be the problem

Comment: Possible, but unlikely. I saw someone else reporting problems with string functions on Firebase, but they were using Node 8, so was trying to see.

Comment: just changed it to node 8, no change. The original sample code had " agent.parameters.date.split " ( with agent as the argument), could this be why?

Comment: Are you sure the parameters are of the expected type (string)?